# Lagging response from accelerometer in android game

Tags: java, android

I am having a little problem with a game i am developing at the moment with the response of the ball to the accelerometer. I have the sensor delay set at Fastest so it should be near instant response to the movement of the phone. However, when the ball is moving, it seems as though there is slight lagging in the response, the ball seems a little jerky sometimes. I cant afford to have this as it is a game based on strategy and steadiness of hands. 
The game code is written in Java.
How would i reduce the lagging in the response?

Regards
A

Comment: GC is a common cause for delays. Please post your code.

Comment: I reviewed the code and it turns out the device was using a lot of memory, so i just stopped other processes on the device and it responds near instantaneously now.